# Send image to third party hardware using bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to Bluetooth technology to connecting the third party devices.

I have googled a lot and found 2 options

1. using core Bluetooth
2. using External Accessory framework (but for this the device should be MFI)

I have some doubts for this

1. If I will use core Bluetooth then can I use my iOS app as Peripheral and Third party device as central?
2. Can we send large data like 5MB images using core Bluetooth i.e Bluetooth 4.0?

If I will use MFI program then I have below doubts
1. as we can enroll into MFI program so after enrolling what we will get from Apple by which we can be able to detect Bluetooth device? Do we get any hardware chip that will be added to third party hardware so that device will be discoverable by the external accessory framework?
2. Do we need to do anything else for MFI?
3. What it will cost for MFI program

Comment: You can have your iOS app act as the peripheral but it is more usual for the iOS device to take the central role.  5MB will take a long time to transfer via BLE.  You need to contact Apple for any details associated with the MFi program